# Unable to typeahead working with Multiselect bootstrap taginputs

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js, bootstrap-tags-input

I have the following code.

```
                <div class="bs-example">
                    <select multiple data-role="tagsinput">
                        {% for tag in result['tag'] %}
                            <option value="{{tag}}" selected="selected">{{tag}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                    <script>
                       $('input[type="text"]').typeahead({
                            source: function (query, process){
                                return $.getJSON('http://localhost:9450/a=query&text="+query+"*:PTN_LABEL&print=fields&printfields=PTN_LABEL&matchdatabase=xxxx&responseformat=json',{
                                    query: query
                                }, function (data){
                                    console.log(data);
                                });
                            }
                       });
                    </script>
                </div>
```

I am unable to get typeahead working with query from the input field in bootstrap tagsinput.

Comment: Can you debug http://localhost:9450 and check if you are getting the value selected in the drop-down there? Check "a" and "text" params.

Comment: I don't think the source function is even getting called.